# select different column based on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a few columns. There are two columns in particular, Nominal & MktBuyAmt.

What I would like to do is when the two values in both columns are the same to use the value in the Nominal column but if the two values are different to select the value in the MktBuyAmt column.

Quick example

```
  Nominal    MktBuyAmt
  7          8
  5          5
  3          3
```

Answer

```
  NewSS
  8
  5
  3
```

Below is my attempt (which I have copied from examples on here) but it returns an error message saying invalid column name 'MktBuyAmt'. The MktBuyAmt that has a red line underneath it is the one where I have Nominal = MktBuyAmt.

```
select Id, Name, Nominal, MktButAmt, 
       case when Nominal = MktBuyAmt 
       then Nominal 
       else MktButAmt end NewSS
from tblA
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as selecting just the `MktBuyAmt` column for every row?

Comment: I think you've got a typo between `MktButAmt` and `MktBuyAmt` but other than that - it's as above, unneeded.

Comment: ah... it's just a typo! sneaky beaky. Have close voted as such.

Comment: thanks for spotting that, half asleep here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Nominal] int, [MktBuyAmt] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Nominal], [MktBuyAmt])
VALUES
    (7, 8),
    (5, 5),
    (3, 3)
SELECT  CASE WHEN NOMINAL = MKTBUYAMT THEN NOMINAL    ELSE MKTBUYAMT END AS NEWSS  FROM #TABLE1
```

output

```
NEWSS
8
5
3
```

Comment: Sorry, just re-read the OP, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

I assume you actually want to get the larger of the two columns, and if this is the case then you can use the below. Otherwise, just select MktBuyAmt as suggested in comments.

```
declare @t table (nominal int, mktbuyamt int)
insert into @t
values
(7,8),
(8,7),
(3,3)

select
case when nominal >= mktbuyamt then nominal else mktbuyamt end as NewSS
from @t
```